# Ruby Invalid break (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby, break

I have an issue with very simple piece of code:

```
def cond(x,y)
       if x =~ /#{y}/
                puts "ok"
        else
                puts "not ok"
                break
        end
end

result = `ls /path/to/some/file | grep something`
cond(result,"nothing")
```

and there I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
./nodeexp.rb: ./nodeexp.rb:13: Invalid break (SyntaxError)
```

Same code but used not in def works fine:

```
result = `ls /path/to/some/file | grep something`
if result =~ /nothing/
        puts "ok"
else
        puts "nie ok"
        break
end
```

What did I miss?

Comment: No, the same code "not in def" doesn't work fine. `break` breaks a loop and must be used in a loop. You can't use `break` in a function (`def`). I assume the context of "not in def" you omitted is a loop.

Comment: @Luatic, that's incorrect in three ways: 1) [break](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement) can be used in a block as well as in a loop; 2) `def` is used to define a method, not a function (module methods are sometimes called "functions"); and 3) methods may contain loops and blocks so obviously they may contain `break` statements.